# Set global time zone

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, momentjs

I am using Moment.js to handle dates in my web application. The server returns all the dates in milliseconds UTC. Now, I have to display the dates applying a specific timezone (based on the user settings).

Is there any way to set the timezone globally instead of changing all the calls to momentjs to handle it?

Comment: Do you mean the user's local time zone of their computer?  Or do you mean a time zone string from your own code, such as `America/New_York`?

Comment: I mean a time zone string coming from the server, such America/New_York. I know I can handle it with momentjs-timezone. My question is: how can I set it once when my application starts instead of modifying all the calls to moment() with moment().tz('America/New_York') ?

Comment: Sorry, that feature doesn't exist.  You can request it in the [moment-timezone issue tracker](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues).  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I have just opened an [issue](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/15).

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You can [set the default timezone in Moment](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/default-timezone/) by using:

```
moment.tz.setDefault(String);
```

#### For example

```
moment.tz.setDefault("America/New_York");
```

Comment: Works well, just remember to add `moment-timezone` from npm and `import moment from "moment-timezone";` instead of importing `moment` from `moment`.

Answer (score 10):

1. `npm install moment-timezone`
2. `var moment = require('moment-timezone');` and use this object
   instead of usual `moment`.
3. `moment.tz.setDefault(String);` where String is [a time zone
   identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

For example:

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');
moment.tz.setDefault("America/New_York");
```

Docs: https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/

Answer (score 3):

Use the moment-timezone library found on the same website: http://momentjs.com/timezone/
It let's you do things like:

```
moment(utcDateTime).tz(settings.timezone).format(settings.dateFormat);
```

I recommend implementing a user class/object that has a service function for translating UTC to the user's timezone. Have a look at this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/guidosch/ofd4unhu/4/

The dates are served as UTC, but the view uses the date formatting method of the user class to adjust and format the UTC date according to the user's preferences.

Answer (score -6):

Having run into this problem in the past, my solution was to create a moment factory that provisioned moment objects rom a base configuration.  You can make it as transparent as requiring moment - referencing your package and using the class just like moment - but in reality you are calling a moment wrapper object that provisions the moment implementations with the selected timeZone.

Answer (score -14):

I've not done extensive testing, but it looks right on cursory tests. I was able to do this with Moment Timezone 0.0.1:

```
var serverTimezoneOffset = <?php echo timezone_offset_get(new DateTimeZone(date_default_timezone_get()), new DateTime('now')) / -60; ?>;
moment.updateOffset(new Date().getTimezoneOffset()-serverTimezoneOffset);
```